# angular uncaught typeerror cannot read properties of undefined

Tags: angular, xmlhttprequest

the following function is calling the service -

```
export class ShowInspectionComponent implements OnInit {
  inspectionList$!: Observable<any[]>;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inspectionList$ = this.service.getInspectionList();
  }
```

when added a breakpoint on the service, it showed the above error -

```
getInspectionList(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.inspectionAPUrl + '/Inspections');
  }
```

sometimes under the network tab in the chrome browser, i also see the data that is to be returned.

Comment: Hi, which part does you get the `undefined`? While in your service,  you should work with `this.http.get<any[]>` since you are returning `Observable<any[]>`.

Comment: thanks Yong for replying -- the following code below basically brings back undefined. ngOnInit(): void {
    this.inspectionList$ = this.service.getInspectionList();
  } . sometimes it seems, the service gets the data, but when assigns to this.inspectionList$, it becomes undefined.